# ReactRouter: How to access route params in component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my web project I try to access route params.

Defined route:

```
<Route path="/meeting/:id">
    <MeetingDetails />
</Route>
```

Component is loaded but I can't access the route params, because `this.props.match` is not defined. How can I access the route param `id`?

```
import React from "react";

export default class MeetingDetails extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(this.props.match);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Details
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `component` prop of `<Route>` to your `<MeetingDetails>` component:

```
<Route path="/meeting/:id" component={MeetingDetails}/>
```